# Creating binary with CMake removes runtime path

Tags: linux, runtime, linker, cmake

I am using CMake to build a program on linux. The program compiles successfully and runs from the project build directory. The program is linked with a custom library in the directory `${HOME}/build/lib`

I have an install stage with:

```
install(TARGETS ProgName RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

When I run `make install` the program gets put in the correct place, but the `cmake` installer removes the runtime path from the binary.

```
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Installing: *binary name*
-- Removed runtime path from "*binary name*"
```

I have read articles on the internet discussing the misuse of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable so I like to keep mine limited to system library locations if possible. I am not sysadmin so I cannot add the location to the default linker search path either.

Does anyone know how I can keep the development-time linking paths when installing or at least customising which paths are added to the runtime?

Cheers

Comment: You should also ensure CMake uses the `ld` equivalent to `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. That ensures your get a `RUNPATH`, not a `RPATH`. `RUNPATH` can be overridden with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, while `RPATH` cannot. It usually matters when `make check` runs in-place in the build directory before the install.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should look at set_target_properties command and the property BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:set_target_properties

Comment: Thanks for this, managed to get it working with the line `set_property(TARGET *binary* PROPERTY INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)` which sets the runtime path to the build linking path. Cheers

Answer (score 14):

Note: if you don't want to modify the `cmake` scripts themselves, setting property around, you can launch you `cmake` with a directive asking to not remove the runtime path:
See "[Variables that Control the Build](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#section_VariablesthatControltheBuild)", with variable: "[`CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH)"

> If true, do not add run time path information.
>
> If this is set to TRUE, then the rpath information is not added to compiled executables.
> The default is to add rpath information if the platform supports it. This allows for easy running from the build tree.
> To omit `RPATH` in the install step, but not the build step, use `CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH` instead.

If the deliveries already contained the right runtime path, that directive will avoid `cmake` to do any modification to the current runtime path included in said deliveries.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=ON xxx.cmake
```

Comment: Super! Thank you, much better than the first answer!

Comment: +1, thanks for this answer, exactly what I was looking for, i.e. make CMake *behave* like it should be doing by default!

Answer (score 0):

This works for CMake 2.8

```
 set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

where `foo` is the target you defined earlier:

```
 project(foo)
 add_executable(foo ...)
  ...
 install(TARGETS foo DESTINATION bin)
  ...
```

Before

```
% sudo make install
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /opt/mystuff/bin/foo
-- Removed runtime path from "/opt/mystuff/bin/foo"
```

After

```
% sudo make install
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /opt/mystuff/bin/foo
-- Set runtime path of "/opt/mystuff/bin/foo" to "/opt/zzyzx/lib:/opt/bar/lib/x86_64"
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what I do, I always get `Set runtime path of "/tmp/bin/program" to "`.  Cmake is far more painful than autotools.

Comment: It seems that on CentOS/Redhat you need to set -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local instead of just /usr