# shared libraries conflicts after installing python / django

Tags: python, django, linux, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I have this issue after installing new packages

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.1, needed by /usr/local/lib/libcpprest.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.0.0 
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.1.1, needed by /usr/local/lib/libcpprest.so, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Is there 2 versions of those shared library in my system?
If yes, How can I fix this warning?

Thanks

Comment: What distribution are you on? Are you installing packages using the package manager? Have you previously installed any packages by hand i.e. circumventing the package manager?

Comment: Please show the `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` you used to build the application. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin I'm using ubuntu 18.04, I installed django using "pip". I got this issue after installing django.

Comment: @jww, I'm using CMAKE
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
target_compile_options (${EXECUTABLE} PUBLIC -std=c++11 -Wall)
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE} boost_system boost_thread pthread glog cpprest ssl crypto)

Comment: Please add additional information to the question; not the comments. You can add it to your question by clicking *Edit* in the lower left-hand corner of the question, and then making the changes.

Comment: Shooting from the hip, I believe you need `-L<path> -Wl,-R,<path> -Wl,--enable-new-dtags` in your `LDFLAGS`. `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags` enables a `RUNPATH`, not an `RPATH`. I think that equates to CMake's `BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH`; also see [Creating binary with CMake removes runtime path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071646/608639). I can only say *I think* because I am not sure if CMake uses `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags` when the option is specified.

Comment: According to [RPATH/RUNPATH](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/RPATH-RUNPATH-td6696135.html) on the CMake mailing list, CMake does not support `RUNPATHs`. If that is still the case, then manually add `-L<path> -Wl,-R,<path> -Wl,--enable-new-dtags` to your `LDFLAGS` and then use `-DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=ON` when invoking CMake.